# Pourquoi « baiser » a-t-il deux sens tellement différents?

Tags: usage, étymologie, choix-de-mot

On dit « *donne-moi un baiser* »  mais « *je veux te baiser* » veut dire autre chose... (Pour ceux parmi nous dont le français n'est pas une langue maternelle, il me semble que cela pourrait créer des situations intéressantes.)

Pourquoi le français n'a-t-il pas un autre mot pour éviter les confusions? Pourquoi le verbe *embrasser* s'utilise à la place de *baiser*?

Comment: On peut noter que "embrasser" a aussi changé de sens au cours du temps. Cf. ["Qui trop embrasse mal étreint"](http://www.oodoc.com/50926-rabelais-pantagruel-qui-trop-embrasse-peu-etreint.php)

Comment: A noter aussi que dans certaines régions de Belgique, _une baise_ est utilisé pour _un baiser_: _Allez m'fi, fait une baise à mamy!_ (Allez, mon enfant, donne un baiser à ta grand-mère)

Comment: Sachant que *embrasser* signifie aussi « prendre dans ses bras, »
notons qu'en japonais aussi, le verbe *étreindre* (抱く) a aussi le sens d'avoir des rapports sexuels.

Comment: Même de nos jours, une expression comme « il a baisé sa joue » ne devrait pas trop choquer, même si ça a un ton précieux (et ça peut attirer quolibets et ironie de ceux qui ont l'esprit mal placé... ^_^)

Comment: En fait, un nombre incroyable de mots sont utilisés pour "sexe" et "argent"... Certains prennent mieux que d'autres...

Comment: Ces deux sens ne sont pas **si** différents, ils sont au moins apparentés ou proches. La plupart des mots ont plusieurs sens, certains en ont plus de dix, parfois des sens qui n'ont pas le moindre début de rapport entre eux (un exemple ironique mais très réel [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sens)). Pardon de le dire, mais je ne comprends pas du tout pourquoi ce serait étrange pour le seul mot *baiser*. Enfin, ce verbe a **aussi** le sens de "arnaquer/tromper/voler", qui est encore bien plus éloigné des deux que tu citais, les deux premiers étant relativement plus proches entre eux.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, *Baiser* avait déjà cette double signification *Donner un baiser* et *Avoir une relation sexuelle* (argot):

> Aristocrates, vous voilà dans le bahut, 
>   Je baiserons vos femmes et vous serez cocus,
>   Aristocrates, je vous vois tous cornus.(bis) — (Anonyme, Le Tombeau des aristocrates, 1791)

Le sens argotique est dérivé du sens original, et n'est apparemment devenu prévalent qu'au XX<sup>e</sup> siècle. Aujourd'hui, outre pour son sens argotique, on n'utilise plus le terme *baiser* que pour *baiser la main*, et on lui préfère le reste du temps son synonyme *embrasser*.

Ce dernier a lui aussi [plusieurs significations](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/embrasser), mais son usage est tout de même bien moins risqué.

Comment: Attention à la typographie des ordinaux (et des siècles) : c'est XVIIIe siècle (avec le *e* en exposant, mais je ne peux pas le faire dans le commentaire). Ni « è », ni « ème ».

Comment: Y a-t-il un tableau des tags HTML à utiliser? A vrai dire, j'ai tendance à éditer en WYSIWYG à l'aide de la barre d'outil du champ texte.

Comment: [Tableau complet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user). Ici, c'est `<sup>e</sup>`

Answer (score 6):

J'ai toujours perçu l'utilisation de *baiser* pour avoir des rapports sexuels comme un euphémisme tirant son origine dans le fait que le second s'accompagne souvent de baisers.

Le sens original d'*embrasser* est de serrer dans ses bras (et c'est un sens qu'il conserve toujours). Comme c'est souvent accompagné de baisers, il a acquit aussi le sens d'en donner.

Answer (score 5):

Le sens original du verbe *baiser* était *donner un baiser*. En lisant le Trésor de la langue française, il me paraît que le sens du mot a glissé par métonymie, et qu'il était désormais employé pour vouloir dire *être en relation amoureuse avec quelqu'un*. On peut constater, en effet, que c'est très proche du sens sexuel actuel, attesté dès 1949.

Answer (score 0):

Let mots souvent font des tours très étranges... *baiser* vient du latin, *basium*, (Kiss), en italien, en espagnol et en portugais la signification est restée l'originale; en français, apparemment, elle dépend de l'article: masculin, toujours "kiss" comme dans les autres langues d'origine latine; si l'article est au féminin alors la signification change à 180°: "fuck, cock", le tout lié aux relations sexuelles. C'est bizarre mais c'est comme ça !

Comment: J'imagine que tu fait référence à *la baiser*. Il ne s'agit pas dans ce cas d'un article féminin mais d'un pronom. Dans *le baiser* ce peut être un article ou un pronom suivant le reste de la phrase.